# How can I turn off Siri's joke responses?

Tags: iphone, ios, siri

I'm using Siri to set short timers, many times in a row: "Set timer for 45 seconds." This is on an iPhone 7 Plus running iOS 10.3.2 (14F89).

It works great, but each time Siri confirms the timer she adds a humorous quip from a short list:

- "Just remember, a watched iPhone never boils."
- "The suspense is killing me."
- "I see you shiver with antici... pation."
- "Roger that. T-minus 45 seconds."

I assume these comments are intended to make Siri seem more human but obviously they have the opposite effect, especially as they are repeated ad nauseam. They're annoying and unprofessional.

I don't want to silence Siri completely; I want verbal confirmation that the timer was set. Ideally "timer set for 45 seconds", or even just "timer set".

Is there any way to turn off Siri's funny comments? I want this primarily for the timer, but I'd be fine with turning chatty mode off globally too.

Things I've tried that don't work:

- Changing language from English (US) to English (UK, Australia, etc.) Different accent, same jokes.
- Saying "Cut the jokes" after a joke. Siri says sorry, but jokes don't stop.

Comment: What iOS? I've never heard Siri make any attempt at humour.... thankfully

Comment: @Tetsujin iPhone 7 Plus running iOS 10.3.2 (14F89). What happens when you tell Siri to set a timer?

Comment: "Set timer for ten minutes"..."OK, ten minutes & counting" Nothing more, nothing less.

Comment: @Tetsujin Every time?

Comment: Yes, she's never said anything other than that, afaik. I once asked for "tea, Earl Grey, hot" a long time ago... no quip even on that one

Comment: @Tetsujin That's the exact behavior I want. Unfortunately my Siri makes a quip from a short list every time. And it's not just me: Google "watched iPhone never boils" for numerous examples of other people encountering this issue.

Comment: Found on MacRumors - might be worth a shot... "You need to say to her "CUT THE JOKES". It works. She says, she's sorry."

Comment: @Tetsujin I just get a Bing search for "[Cut the jokes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bin0M.jpg)"

Comment: Might have to try it immediately after a joke, for context.

Comment: @WilliamTFroggard You're right, saying it after a joke prompts "I'm sorry." But she still tells jokes when setting a timer, so I think that's just more fake-humanizing and not an actual setting.

Comment: @Robert It's possible that this is a learned behavior, and she'll need some persistence to learn to not tell jokes anymore. I'm uncertain how her humor's implemented behind the scenes.

Comment: @WilliamTFroggard I set a timer then told it to "cut the jokes" ten times in a row. Still got a joke every time.

Comment: @Robert Then perhaps it does nothing. ;)

Comment: Sadly... very sadly, Siri has started doing this to me too since iOS 11. My fix - stop using it :/

Comment: I too use Siri for setting a timer, typically when I'm grilling. I agree with others that all the "extra" cutesy stuff is annoying. you should be able to turn it off.

Answer (score 5):

**You can't.**

Due to the design of Siri, you cannot change the way she behaves. This behavior is all run off of apple servers and is the same for every person.

Siri *is* able to learn behaviors but that is limited to repeated behaviors like opening an app and the way you speak.

So no,  because of the way that Siri was written, you cannot disable her "jokes". Sorry about that.

---

**EDIT:**
Source: myself after listening and reading up on Apple's privacy info, and the Internet's many forum posts complaining about this topic.

Also, from more reading, I found out that people have varying amounts of times that this happens to them. Generally, people who don't mind it (like me) don't really notice it. People who are bothered by it appear to notice it more often, so it becomes more of a problem.

You can provide feedback about this to apple via **[apple.com/feedback](http://www.appple.com/feedback)**

Comment: Do you have a source for this? @Tetsujin commented said Siri does *not* do this for them, so that suggests at the very least that this behavior is not the same for every person.

Comment: @Robert what version of iOS are you on?

Comment: As I said in the question, iOS 10.3.2 (14F89) on an iPhone 7 Plus. Does that make a difference?

Comment: @Robert behaviors *are* controlled by iOS. Still, you are not able to disable attitude

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand. Why did you want to know what version of iOS I'm using?

Comment: @Robert If you were on something like iOS 6, Siri would be nothing like they Siri today and therefore the answer to your problem would be to update your phone.